# Problems on Big Sur with Magma Computer Algebra System crashing

Tags: crash, big-sur

This question relates to the MAGMA Computer Algebra System based at the University of Sydney (not the other MAGMA about Matrix Algebra on GPUs).

I originally posted it on StackExchange, but someone there correctly pointed out that it is really a Big Sur question, and that I would more chance of an answer here.

I have used MAGMA on Mac OSX for many years, but recently, I am experiencing crashes on very simple code that previously worked.

My experiments have led me to suspect that it is a recent update to Mac OSX 11 (Big Sur) that is behind the problems. I have prepared a MWE of the problem and tested it on about 5 Macs, and it has always failed on the ones running Big Sur, and never failed on the ones not running Big Sur.

I detected this problem when I was using one of Magma's databases, in this case the lists of transitive groups. The error, however, seems to be very low-level and much more to do with the system than MAGMA.

So here is the definition of a test function that simply creates each transitive group in turn, and then returns true. It doesn't actually do anything except read in and create each of the transitive groups in turn. Any code manipulating transitive groups will have a similar loop at its heart.

```
function testDeg(deg)
  for i in [1..NumberOfTransitiveGroups(deg)] do
    g := TransitiveGroup(deg,i);
  end for;
  return true;
end function;
```

If I run this function for degree 24, by calling

```
testDeg(24);
```

then after creating some number of groups, it crashes.

```
> testDeg(24);

testDeg(
    deg: 24
)
TransitiveGroup(
    d: 24,
    n: 1194
)
In file "/Applications/Magma/package/Group/GrpData/trngps.m", line 18, column
51:
>>     return TransitiveGroup(TransitiveGroupDatabase(d), n);
                                                     ^
Runtime error in 'TransitiveGroupDatabase': GetLibraryRoot() is set to
/Applications/Magma/libs but the file GetLibraryRoot()/data/TrnGps/trans.dat
either does not exist or cannot be read (Interrupted system call).
```

In this case, the crash occurred on group number 1194, but this number will be different if I re-run it.

This is definitely not related to a capacity issue - there are 25000 transitive groups of degree 24, which is tiny compared to what MAGMA can hold in memory. It is my more recent, larger and higher-powered Macs which are running Big Sur and crashing, while the older Macs have no problems.

The error message is claiming that a certain file - `trans.dat` - does not exist or cannot be read. However the file certainly *does* exist, because the previous 1193 iterations of the loop have each used the exact same file.

So somehow, while MAGMA is trying to read this file, something goes wrong and generates an "Interrupted System Call".

I have contacted the MAGMA developers, but they cannot replicate the error because, of course, it works perfectly on their old non-Big Sur Macs.

What I want to know is whether this is a widespread issue definitely relating to Big Sur, or just something to do with my setup.

So if you are a MAGMA user on a Mac, then I would be very grateful if you could run the above testing code and just let me know (in the comments) whether it crashed or not, and which version of OSX you are running.

Of course if anyone recognises the same problem arising from other software, then I'd like to hear about that as well, especially if there is a known fix.

(This morning I just updated from OSX 11.1 to OSX 11.2 and the problem still remains, and I have updated Magma to V2.25-8).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to update CommandLineTools, vers. 12.4, the latest one. I had often similar problems with C++ and Rust not finding something already installed.